# How to Use "random" function in DrScheme R5RS

Tags: random, scheme, racket, r5rs

I want to use a "random" function in DrScheme R5Rs but it says it does not exist. But it is possible to use in "Advanced student", I need to use it in R5RS, what is the way to do it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*NB: DrScheme is very old. You should perhaps upgrade to a supported version of [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/).*

R6RS has random number through [SRFI-27: Sources of Random Bits](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-27/srfi-27.html).

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs)
        (srfi :27))

(random-integer 10) ; ==> 9
```

R5RS can for some implementations stil use SRFI-27, but it's not entirely portable. Under racket one might do this in R5RS mode:

```
#!r5rs    
(#%require srfi/27) ; non portable way to include library

(random-integer 10) ; ==> 9
```

You can also include the procedure supplied in the racket languages, but that would be a tad lesser portable:

```
#!r5rs    
(#%require (only racket/base random)) ; non portable way to include non portable library procedure

(random 10) ; ==> 9
```